# disable htaccess IndexIgnore *

Tags: .htaccess, directory

I want to enable `IndexIgnore *` on the root of my website but I want some special folder to show index files. but because `IndexIgnore *` is enable on the root, in sub-folders nothing will be shown!

is there anyway to disable `IndexIgnore *` on special sub-folder?

Comment: Did you look at the next entry down in the documentation?

Comment: which documentation?

Comment: The HTTPd documentation available on the Apache website.